# Proper way to create and connect to a Socket in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm getting to a point in the development of an Android app where I've reached a stumbling block: how to create, manage, and connect to a `Socket` in Android.

My app needs to keep a persistent TCP connection to the server in order to exchange JSON formatted strings back and forth. After reading up on the subject, I've determined the best way forward is to create a `Service` when the app starts up (by extending the `Application` class and starting the `Service` in `onCreate()`), then read from/write to the `Socket` as needed. But how do I do that?

I obviously know how to create a `Service` and how to create and work with a `Socket`. But I don't know the best way to interact with one in an Android environment. Should I create an `AsyncTask` whenever I want to write data? Should I use `Intents`? Any help on the subject would be wonderful. And if my question isn't clear, I'll be more than happy to clarify anything.

Comment: check netty libs for possible use on android : https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio/issues/62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the service, you can simply listen as you would in a regular Java application. This means you can safely wait for IO as you normally would.

You will have to use `Intent` when you wish to notify your activities about new data arrival using `sendBroadcast` and receiving it to your activities by either registering a `BroadcastReceiver` using `registerReceiver` or modifying your manifest file.

[This is a good tutorial that may help you with broadcasting for Service <-> Activity communication.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was thinking about this problem incorrectly. What I need is to implement a ["Bound Service"](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), which will give my `Activity` an interface to interact with in order to send and receive messages.

Here's a [link to the tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Local_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example) I found which gives an excellent overview of how to do this.